# Foundation 6.5 - Multiple XY Grid gutters

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

Can I use Foundation XY Grid SASS mixins to create grid gutter variations?

For example, I would like to have a grid with a 30px gutter, and a grid with a 10px gutter. No other differences between the grids.

```
<!-- Regular (30px) grid gutter ->
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="cell medium-6">
  </div>
  <div class="cell medium-6">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Custom (10px) grid gutter -->
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x--small">
  <div class="cell medium-6">
  </div>
  <div class="cell medium-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Foundation v6.5, you can use the [`xy-gutters()`](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#xy-gutters) mixin to generate custom gutters on an element. However for the gutters of a margin cell, gutters are implemented in a way that require the cell width to be updated with the gutter width. The [`xy-cell-static()`](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#xy-cell-static) mixin takes care of that. Here is an example of use:

```
.grid-margin-x--small > .cell {
  @include xy-cell-static($gutters: 10px);
}
```

We know that this is not ideal and we already worked on some big refactor and various improvement for v6.6.0 in the XY Grid API to make the generation of custom grid/cell/gutters way easier. See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/11405 for more details.

Comment: Thanks @ncoden, this is helpful. Is there a way to use `xy-cell-static` that avoids having to redefine sizes? i.e. respect `cell small-4` sizing, but also define the new gutter for the cell?

Comment: No. This is how margin gutters works. You cannot change them without having to redefine the size. If only the "margin" property is changed and not the width, the cell will be displayed badly.